# Event listener not firing in Vue

Tags: javascript, events, vuejs3

I want to toggle an element's visibility on keypress in Vue. The problem is I see the event is attached to the element but is not firing.
the template is :

```
    <h1 v-show="typeWriterEffectVisible">
    <div id="game-board" data-v-d95dafd8="">
     <div class="letter-row">
      <div class="letter-box"></div>
      <div class="letter-box"></div>
      // etc
```

Vue:

```
<script setup>

let typeWriterEffectVisible = ref(true);

onMounted(() => {
   const el = document.querySelector(
    "#game-board > .letter-row:first-child > .letter-box:first-child"
  );

  // add eventlistener to toggle off typewriter effect on page
  el.addEventListener("keyup", () => {
    console.log("Im in toggle");
    typeWriterEffectVisible.value = false;
  });
```

From the DOM inspector I see the event is attached to the element but eventlistener callback is never invoked. If I change el.addEventListener to document.addEventListener it works. But then event fires on any keystroke on page which is not efficient or necessary. Any insights welcome...

Comment: `el` is a bog-standard `div`, which you won't be able to focus the cursor to, so the keyup won't fire, change it to an input element or make it editable, additionally you shouldn't be putting divs in h1 tags

Comment: Sorry that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

for vanilla js to work with vue make sure it is after your vue instance in that script.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).